# savetxt with both strings and float in exponential format

Tags: python

I want to save in a filetxt my the values of my variables

```
a= np.array(['a','b'])
b= np.array([[1.32313000e-07, 0.2],[0.3, 4.32313000e-06]])
```

Using:

```
np.savetxt("foo", np.hstack((zip(a),b)), delimiter="\t", fmt='%s')
```

I got a file like this:

```
a 1.3231 0.2
b 0.3 4.3231
```

Now the problem is that for float in exponential format I have wrong values (1.3231, 4.3231).

So, I would like to use ftm = '%.4f', but it is not possible when combining both strings and floats.

How could I convert the exponential format for float so that I can obtain the file:

```
a 0.0000 0.2000
b 0.3000 0.0000
```

Comment: Works fine for me, my file contains 1.32313e-07 and 4.32313e-06 instead. Are you sure the above code produces the problem for you? (I'm actually sure it doesn't, as the a= line is missing a `]`).

Comment: You are right about the variable a. Anyway, I would like to convert the exponential format 1.32313000e-07 to decimal like 0.0000.

Answer (score 0):

Build another array defined with only 4 decimal places and then, save to txt:

```
a= np.array(['a','b'])
b= np.array([[1.32313000e-07, 0.2],[0.3, 4.32313000e-06]])
c = []
for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(b):
    c.append([float('%.4f' % x), float('%.4f' % y)])

c = np.array(c)
np.savetxt("foo", np.hstack((zip(a),c)), delimiter="\t", fmt='%s')
```

Comment: What if b is not a 2x2 matrix but a nxn matrix, where n is large?